# Where is my database of sqlite in windows phone 8.1 (Universal windows App)?

Tags: windows, sqlite, uwp, windows-phone, win-universal-app

I am searching my database named as Student.db  but i am not able find ?
Sqlite store data in ApplicationData.Current.Local location but where is it?

```
SQLiteAsyncConnection connection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection("Student.db");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Local Storage can be found here :
`C:/Users/YourName/AppData/Local/Packages/YourPackageName/LocalState`